# creating own emoji for custom keyboard in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, uiimage, custom-keyboard

In Xcode, I try to add some emoji to my custom keyboard. I want to use an image for the emoji.

As i dont know how to convert an image to emoji, im having trouble in creating a button that send an image of the button in messaging.How do i create a button that send an image of the button in messaging?

I had tried to convert an image to NSdata ,but the attempt was failed.

This is some of my codes

```
-(void) addGestureToKeyboard{
[self.keyboard.deleteKey addTarget:self action:@selector(pressDeleteKey) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.keyboard.enterKey addTarget:self action:@selector(pressEnterKey) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.keyboard.nextKey addTarget:self action:@selector(advanceToNextInputMode) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.keyboard.smileyKey addTarget:self action:@selector(pressSmileyKey:) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


for (UIButton * keys in self.keyboard.keysArray) {
    [keys addTarget:self action:@ selector(pressKey:) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
}

-(void) pressDeleteKey{
[self.textDocumentProxy deleteBackward];
}

-(void) pressEnterKey{
[self.textDocumentProxy insertText:@"\n"];
}

-(void) pressKey:(UIButton *) key{
[self.textDocumentProxy insertText:[key currentTitle]];
}

-(void) pressSmileyKey:(UIButton *) skey{
NSData *imageData= UIImageJPEGRepresentation([skey currentImage], 1.0);
[self.textDocumentProxy insertText: imageData];
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code to more precisely pinpoint your problem? This will increase the chances that you will get an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have added some codes and more information about the question.